# Как вытащить таблицу c помощью System.Data.SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

Как вытащить таблицу из SQLITE?

Comment: Запрос `SELECT 1;` что-то возвращает? Если да и на целевой БД данные есть, то может в путях ошибка и он создает какую-нибудь чистую бд в другом месте.

Comment: Никаких Exception'ов тоже не возникает?

Comment: Вы под дебагером проходитесь? До какой позиции он доходит? Как минимум, если подставить `new SQLiteCommand("SELECT 1", connection);` без всего лишнего в исходный код, он должен был упасть на строке `host = reader["origin_url"].ToString();`.

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения синтаксиса и логики код корректен.

Как вариант, возможно, что косяк в условии:

```
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(host) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(user) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(pass))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}",host,user,pass);
                            }
```

Быть может в вашей базе нету таких строк, которые удоволитворяют сразу 3-ем условиям?

Или например, вы расшифровываете пароль и получаете `NULL`.

Попробуйте убрать условие и посмотреть что будет.

Или может быть ошибок нету из-за того, что у вас какой-нибудь глобальный `try/catch` стоит.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348122/how-to-temporarily-deactivate-all-try-catch-blocks Сделай как написано тут. Тогда ты сможешь ловить все исключения независимо от наличия try/catch

Comment: Поставь точку останова там и посмотри, попадаешь ли ты вообще в этот участок кода или нет. Может у тебя данный метод вообще не вызывается.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244452/sqlite-data-source-cannot-be-empty